# Google Datastore Client Parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am hoping to get some help with Parsing data retrieved from the Google DataStore Client in Python.

I am required to create a process in which I have to parse some data taken from the datastore. I am currently calling to retrieve data via this method: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity

If I am to print what is returned I get the below:

```
<Entity(u'Example', u'1000') {u'some_data': True, u'some_more_data': False}>
```

If I could be shown an example on how to best parse the information returned in the Dict I would be very grateful, so that I can take each property and its value in a For Each Loop. I.e:

```
'some_data': True
```

Thanks for your time,
Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a working solution.

```
from google.cloud import datastore

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

def parse_example_list():
    kind = 'Kind'
    name = 'Name'
    key = datastore_client.key(kind, name)
    returned_entity = datastore_client.get(key)

    property_list = {}

    for p in returned_entity.items():
        property_list[p[0]] = p[1]

    return property_list
```

This returns:

```
{u'my_first_property': u'My Propertys Value'}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, properties can be accessed just like object attributes.

For example, after you retrieve your entity:

```
key = client.key("yourkey")
example = client.get(key)
```

You can access its properties by their name and use them

```
print "'some_data': " + example.some_data
print "'some_more_data': " + example.some_more_data
```

To get a list of an entity's properties, use the instance_properties() method:

```
for property in example.instance_properties():
    value = getattr(example, property)
```

---

Read more: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-google-app/9780596157517/ch04s06.html

Comment: Thanks for this Neri, I tried this unfortunately it did not solve my problem. However, I have found a working solution I have posted as a Answer to the question!